# Bitrix24: Fill in listvalue via the Api with lists.element.add

Tags: api, bitrix

I to choose a list-value via the API into Bitrix

```
CRest::call('lists.element.add',
        [ 'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID' => 'lists',
         'IBLOCK_ID' => '134',
         'ELEMENT_CODE' => 'element'.$entry[134] ,
         'FIELDS' => [
         'NAME' =>  'TEST'.$leadID, 
         'PROPERTY_1430' => 'YES or NO' ,
         ]
        ]
```

Ho do i set the Value for Protpery_1430? Here "Yes or NO"

There is a screenshot of the values of the Ja (Yes) and (NO):
[image: There is a screenshot of the values of the Ja (Yes) and (NO]

Some help would be nice :)
Roland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the list variant identifier; e.g.:

```
CRest::call('lists.element.add', [
    'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID' => 'lists',
    'IBLOCK_ID' => '134',
    'ELEMENT_CODE' => 'element'.$entry[134] ,
    'FIELDS' => [
        'NAME' =>  'TEST'.$leadID, 
        'PROPERTY_1430' => 2463, // or 2464
    ]
];
```

If you can't use identifiers and need to use values,
use the [lists.field.get](https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/lists/fields/lists_field_get.php) method and find the identifier by the value from the `DISPLAY_VALUES_FORM` field.